# jQuery filter class that contains certain value

Tags: jquery

in jQuery, how do i filter all contents that contain certain class?

HTML:

```
<div class='item 10'>10</div>
<div class='item 20'>20</div>
<div class='item 30'>30</div>
<div class='item 40'>40</div>
<div class='not-an-item 50'>50</div>
```

what i've tried:

```
var classList = $(".item").attr('class').split(/\s+/);
if(classList[1] == '10' || lassList[1] == '30'){
    $(".item").hide();

}
```

correct output:

```
<div class='item 20'>20</div>
<div class='item 40'>40</div>
<div class='not-an-item 50'>50</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what criteria you're using to to distinguish between classes. So you only want to hide classes `10 and `30`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method or the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method to reduce the set of elements. With `.has()` you keep all elements that match a certain selector, while `.not()` keep all elements that doesn't match the selector.

For more advanced filtering, your can use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

If I understand your question correctly, you could use `.filter()` with a filtering-function. Something like this:

```
$(".item").filter(function() {
   return !($(this).hasClass("10") || $(this).hasClass("30"));
}).hide();
```

Comment: yes! you did understand it correctly! what if i want to filter a value? like if($(this).attr('class').toInt() > 50)? how can i do that?

Comment: You're missing a bracket after `hasClass("30")`, and shouldn't it be `return ($(this).hasClass("10") || $(this).hasClass("30"));`? I thought OP wants to hide `10` and `30`?

Comment: @snuffn Thanks, fixed now. According to them comment in OP's code example, I believe he wants to hide all elements but those with class 10 and 30.

Comment: Oh okay, my bad then. Because first he says he wants to hide all except 10 and 30, but then he says the correct output is 20, 40 and 50.

Comment: @Tom91136 That would be a bit trickier. In your filter function you would have to split the class attribute on space, loop over each class and see if can be parsed into a number, and if it can then compare it to 50. Return true if any of the classes is higher than 50, otherwise return false.

Comment: @snuffn Yeah I realize that I might be wrong as well. If what OP wants is the other way around, then he can get rid of the `!` in the filter function return.

Comment: @Christofer Nah, I think you're right, as he said in his comment above that you understood his question correctly. I still don't understand his question, but that's okay. :), and +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
function hideItem(target) {
    $('div.item').filter(function() {
        var num = parseInt( this.className.split(/\s/)[1], 10 );
        if(target instanceof Array) {
          return $.inArray(num, target) >= 0; 
        } else return num > target;  
    }).hide();
}
hideItem([10,30]); // will hide item with class 10 and 30 
                   // and you can give any number of class
```

But if you want to hide `item` with class `> 20`(suppose) then just call it like;

```
hideItem(20);
```

Comment: Good example +1. One small issue though, this would require that the number is always the second class in the class attribute, right? Perhaps it would be nice to loop over the classes for each element, looking for the number.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this..

```
$("div.item").hide();
$("div.item").not('div.10, div.30').show();
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaNSJ/1)**

Comment: @snuffn Please check the fiddle link and then comment. I think you're confused with not selector.

Comment: I was confused with OP's question, as I thought he wants to hide `.10` and `.30`. So, I think you can leave it like you had it before `$("div.item").not('div.10, div.30').hide();​`. And +1 for your solution.